# Match text names in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to merge different data.tables with artist data. However, artist names are spelled in a different way in some of my datasets. I am looking for an easy and convenient way to match these artist names so that I give each artist an ID which makes it easier to merge my datasets. I am still quite new to R and I was wondering if you could give me some guidance on this topic. The artist names are basically character strings in different data.tables.

Comment: Reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?revalue` from `library(plyr)` in order to correct the names, and then merge them

```
dt_age <- data.table(artist=c("Dali","Van Gogh"),
                 age=c(85,37))
dt_paintings <- data.table(artist=c("dali","van gogh"),
                     paintings=c("The peristence of Memory","The Starry Night"))

merge(dt_age,dt_paintings,by="artist") # this is empty

artist_correct <- c("dali"="Dali",
                        "van gogh"="Van Gogh"
                    )
dt_paintings$artist <- revalue(dt_paintings$artist,artist_correct)

merge(dt_age,dt_paintings,by="artist") # this is correct after we correct the names
```